# FInd out duplicate lines

Tags: command-line, uniq

I have a file which contain following content.

```
Hi
abcd
Hi
abc
hello
hello
xyz
hello
```

I want the find out duplicate lines as well as howmany times it is repeteing.My expected output is as below.

```
2 Hi
3 hello
```

I have used following command alreay which give me duplicate line come one after the other (i.e Hello Hello it works but Hello hi Hello it didn't work)

```
uniq -d filename
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `sort` the input file first before passing to `uniq` to make same lines sequential/adjacent:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -dc
```

`-c` will count the number of occurrences of repeated lines.

**Example:**

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -dc
3 hello
2 Hi

$ sort file.txt | uniq -dc | sort -k1,1n  ## Your expected output
2 Hi
3 hello
```